What is Nagarjuna's Tetralemma?
Nagarjuna's Tetralemma.
You can follow the links for more, but from what I could gather, Wikipedia offers only a sketch of Nagarjuna's tetralemma and hence this query.
Let's get right to the point.
For any proposition p there are only 4 possibilities:

p
¬p
p ∧ ¬p
¬(p ∨ ¬p) ≡ ¬p ∧ ¬¬p [DeMorgan's Law]

All 4 are negated by Nagarjuna.
The idea that I have is that negation of one lemma should take you to the other lemma e.g. negating p takes you to ¬p and negating ¬p takes you to p. So lemmas 1 and 2 are ok.
However this is not the case with lemmas 3 and 4. If I negate p ∧ ¬p , I don't land on ¬(p ∨ ¬p) and the same for ¬(p ∨ ¬p), negating it doesn't result in p ∧ ¬p. In fact negating the lemmas 3 and 4 lead you to p ∨ ¬p (the law of the excluded middle).
What am I getting wrong here?
Gracias.

Translating Nagarjuna into classical logic is not a good idea, he clearly rejects it,  de Morgan and double negation laws in particular. The last option is meant to reject that p is neither true nor false. Such a thing is called truth value gap in modern parlance, and it is dual to the truth value glut where it is both true and false. Pararconsistent (no LNC) and intuitionistic (no LEM) logics are well known to be dual to each other, and both can be used to treat the Liar, for example, see IEP. Nagarjuna's 3 and 4 reject exactly those options.

@Conifold, I see. So DeMorgan doesn't apply. You mean to say we can view Nagarjuna's tetralemma as outlining entire logical systems? So when Nagarjuna rejects p ∧ ¬p, he's saying no to paraconsistent logics and when he denies ¬(p ∨ ¬p), he's declining intuitionist logics. Isn't that affirming classical logic with LNC + LEM (2 of the 3 laws of thought)?

You are still embroiled in double negation, rejection does not amount to affirmation of anything for Nagarjuna, and classical logic is rejected in 1 and 2. Those symbolic formulas are counterproductive, think of assigning logical status/value to p instead. He does not need to outline entire logics to reject all four values they might assign to p: true, false, glut or gap. This covers classical, paraconsistent, intuitionistic and many other logics, and this way he rejects them all.

@Conifold, si, I have issues with double negation. It's hard to suss out what Nagarjuna actually meant. He described 4 "corners" (catuskoti) and denies all 4 possibilities/corners, as listed in the OP. Do you have any idea about the nature of Nagarjuna's denial (I hesitate to call it negation for fear of conflating it with classical negation).

It is a pretty common sense of rejection, just because one rejects existence of God, say, does not mean they affirm his non-existence, agnostics reject both. Nagarjuna goes much further:"Emptiness is the relinquishing of all views.
For whomever emptiness is a view, that one has achieved nothing."

@Conifold, cool! Agnostics operate within classical logic, yes? How does agnosticism differ from Nagarjunaism? I noticed, whether correctly/wrongly can't tell, that Nagarjuna denies p ∧ ¬p (see 3rd corner). He however does not deny p ∨ ¬p, he denies ¬(p ∨ ¬p).

Not if you want to model rejection by classical negation, which it was never meant to model. There is no analog for suspension or "relinquishing" of judgment in classical logic either, it does not even contain its own truth predicate. So formulas like p ∧ ¬p or p ∨ ¬p cannot express what Nagarjuna has in mind at all, which are potential truth values of p, you need to drop these formulas out of your thinking.

@Conifold, si Nagarjunaism is (radically?) different from most logics a philosopher will encounter, but we can work on Nagarjuna's tetralemma from a classical logical standpoint, no? What is he saying then? How does, that is, classical logic parse Nagarjunaism? Not in any meaningful way, huh?

@Conifold, I would like you to post your comments as an answer so I can accept and maybe have a little discussion. I quoted you in answering myself (weird). Well, the Wikipedia article on the Tetralemma has a paragraph, too sketchy to be of any value, regarding finding yourself hopping from one corner to the other ... as you reject each corner.


You are still embroiled in double negation, rejection does not amount to affirmation of anything for Nagarjuna, and classical logic is rejected in 1 and 2. Those symbolic formulas are counterproductive, think of assigning logical status/value to p instead. He does not need to outline entire logics to reject all four values they might assign to p: true, false, glut or gap. This covers classical, paraconsistent, intuitionistic and many other logics, and this way he rejects them all. ~ @Conifold


This part is what I don't get

For Nagarjuna perhaps not on the conventional level of truth to reject them all, at least when he wrote something about Madhyamaka originally he had to follow common logic and language rules to be at least readable...

Hi @DoubleKnot, I was expecting Conifold. I don't know if this is because of biased documentation, but I find Indian logic to be pretty advanced for its time. Wiki articles report that George Boole and other contemporary logicians drew on the Indian system (conveniently translated) to make major advancements in Western Logic. I'd say, ergo, that the critical equivalence p≡¬¬p existed since antiquity. However when I apply it to the Tetralemma, I end up with the LEM for denials 3 and 4 (see OP).

The negations of both 3 and 4 above is just classic logic's LEM, so Nagarjuna's rejection here means rejection of paraconsistent logic in favor of classic logic's LEM as commonly adopted anyway. And the further rejection of the negations for Nagarjuna here means he was an early strict intuitionist or held some aspects of intuitionism to reject non-constructive tautological sophistic assertions as valid or useful in his view. So the double rejection may yield more insight from the 4 primodial combinations than simply accepting the Tetralemma or only reject once...

@DoubleKnot, I don't know much about intuitionism, except that it maybe rejects LEM. I suppose I'm trying to see what Nagarjuna looks like in classical logic. Since Nagarjunian rejection is special, shouldn't he have also said ¬(p ∨ ¬p). no to LEM?

Basically he just criticized every kind of logic here via negation, rejection of negation, not unlike Hegel's dialectic sublation and evolution of the World Spirit, and this makes sense since each kind of logic has their issues when thrown into certain cases...
